# Ionic Cordova Youtube Video Player Error: console.warn: Ionic Native: tried calling YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo, but Cordova is not available

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

I've been trying to get my app on Ionic3 to use Youtube Video Player and Streaming Media Cordova plugins but both return the same error:

I've looked at every single Stack Overflow feed and was unable to find a clear answer to to solve this. I've tried updating npm, deleting node_modules and package_lock... the closest thing I found to a potential lead is that one thread reported that this warning message can be thrown in the event that the specific function your calling within the cordova plugin library either a) no longer exists or b) doesn't exist for the platform (e.g., iOS) in which you're running.

I know I configured my app.module.ts correctly, but here's my home.ts (the startVideo function is fired when I click a button on the home UI):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StreamingMedia, StreamingVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/streaming-media';
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private streamingMedia: StreamingMedia, private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer) {
    // this.launchVideo();
    this.youtube.openVideo('eo362o5XEhw');
  }

startVideo() {
    let options: StreamingVideoOptions = {
  successCallback: () => { console.log('Video played') },
  errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error streaming') },
  orientation: 'portrait',
  shouldAutoClose: true,
  // controls: false
};

this.streamingMedia.playVideo('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eo362o5XEhw', options);
}

}
```

Any and all guidance would be much appreciated – thank you!

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: Testing on Ionic App on iPhone X